# Casement Windows: Install Thru Wall A/C Indoors & Exhaust with Ducting

Tags: hvac, windows, air-conditioning, ducts, cooling

A family member has a business in a century-old building that only has industrial casement, awning, and pivot windows. There's no central A/C & a mini-split can't be hung outside the building. The only thing they can do is remove portions of the windowpanes for exhaust of portable A/Cs. The panes are small and do not fit a square casement A/C unit. The space is approx 700 sq ft & business activities produce heat.

We had an idea if it'd be possible to cut holes above the doors of 2 adjacent rooms, hang max capacity thru-the-wall A/Cs above each door (**indoors**), and use ducting to direct the exhaust out each removed windowpane. Obviously this isn't very efficient, but would there be a high risk of the A/Cs breaking down? Can anyone recommend a malleable type of ducting that can be shaped around the back of the units? Water drainage wouldn't be an issue as the climate is very dry.

Comment: When I moved into my house, there was a central (gas fired) furnace, but no AC. A year later, we replaced the furnace (it was time to go), and _added_ AC. The AC unit sits outside and pumps cold refrigerant through a heat exchanger installed in the duct work. What's wrong with doing that to your commercial building? Seems to be much easier than re-doing windows or attempting to repurpose exterior venting window AC units to vent indoors.

Comment: @FreeMan I don't believe that OP mentioned existing ductwork at any point. The building could very well be heated via boiler and radiant heat. So to answer your question, the $20k-$30 price tag for a brand new HVAC system is likely stopping them. However they should consider a mini-split with one or more ceiling heads such as https://www.homedepot.com/p/Pioneer-12000-BTU-1-Ton-Ductless-Mini-Split-22-SEER-8-Way-Cassette-Air-Conditioner-with-Heat-Pump-230V-CYB012GMFILCAD-16/313980078. I cannot comment on quote prices though.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus this is why pricing questions are off-topic. I finally had that HVAC system replaced a month ago and it was $9k for a 2000 sq/ft house. A system for 700 sq/ft should be _much_ less expensive. Well, at least if he's not where you live. ;) Your point about not having duct work is very valid, though. OP didn't say.

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, a $9k equipment quote is fairly common for a furnace+A/C combo depending on the efficiency rating you wish to achieve. I take it you've never been quoted for ductwork? Tack on $6k-$15k if everything is open and accessible.

Comment: #MonkeyZeus -- Unfortunately the mini-split outdoor unit isn't allowed to be hung outside the building. Likewise, there is no systemic heat thru the building. The building is in vintage condition from the 1920s. We're leaning towards hanging the units indoors, but we do need some type of malleable ducting that can be shaped.